# clearCookie() not working - node express js

Tags: node.js, express

Every time need to clear browser cache to run below code. Otherwise unable to clear cookie.

```
res.clearCookie('node_express', {path:'/'});
```

Comment: use no cache to clear the cache

Comment: or kindly post code here so we should give you proper suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should use middleware to add no-cache headers and clear cookie, it will not require clearing cache as well cookie manually on every request.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  // -1 setting up request as expired and re-requesting before display again. 
  res.header('Expires', '-1');
  res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  res.clearCookie('<cookie name>', {path: '/'}).status(200).send('Ok.')
  // or if above not working then use
  res.cookie('<cookie name>', '', { expires: new Date(1), path: '/' })
  next();
});
```

Comment: Hi,

I have tried, but still having the same issue.

Comment: OK I just come online

Comment: @K.Paul can you post your code so I can get the proper idea.

Comment: @K.Paul you wanted to clear browser cache as well as browser cookie

Comment: @K.Paul Sometime it may possible that cookie may not delete so you should assign blank value to the cookie it will helpful to you.

Comment: Actually, I did that, 1st I wrote code for assign a blank value to cookie and after that clear the cookie. 

But, that problem was for redirecting to cart page. It was redirected without update the cookie. I have fixed it. 

Anyways, thanks for your help man. :)

Comment: My final codes. you can check it if you want.

https://github.com/sendmail2krrish/eCommerce-site-using-Node-Express-js

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
res.clearCookie('SESSIONID', {path: '/', domain: 'localhost'}).send();
```

'res' is the response parameter.
You may find 'cookieName' and path details by inspecting code of page and in Chrome navigate to Application and then click Cookies under Storage.

The domain need not necessarily be localhost. It will depend on your specific use case.

Note: Having domain before path did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue but resolved.
In logout function my cookie wasn't being sent to server that's why it's happening.
Use this:

```js
const res = await axios.post('/logout', {}, {withCredentials:true})
```

u